# Can't run Laravel Horizon, error in Laravel\Horizon\ProvisioningPlan::__construct()

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

I'm getting the following error:

`Argument 2 passed to Laravel\Horizon\ProvisioningPlan::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/camilo/Documents/development/laravel/via-express/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/ProvisioningPlan.php on line 58`

I don't know why, the horizon installation is fresh. I ran the following commands:

```
composer require laravel/horizon
php artisan vendor:publish
php artisan horizon
```

Also, can't find anything related to this error on the internet. Any ideas?